# A simple proof in the form of an inequality

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

Proof that for all $a, b$ are elements of $\mathbb{R}$ : $(a+b)^2\geq 4ab$.

Does it satisfies after doing some simple arithmetic to say that $(a-b)^2\geq 0$?

Or do I need to go over all the cases for which the inequality holds?

Comment: It's fine, if you can show that that is the case.

Comment: So that's the end of the proof? Ok, thank you.

Comment: Well, you have the *end* of the proof, but without the middle, your proof is still incomplete.

Answer (score 2):

This should be enough of a proof:

$$(a+b)^2 \geq 4ab$$ 
$$\Leftarrow a^2+2ab+b^2\geq 4ab$$
$$\Leftarrow a^2-2ab+b^2\geq 0$$
$$\Leftarrow (a-b)^2\geq 0$$
The bottom inequality is true, since squares are never negative, so the top inequality is also true.

Comment: It is better to replace $\Leftarrow$ with $\iff$.

Comment: This is not necessary for the proof. I was demonstrating a minimal proof.